# MVC razor page jQuery fires but doesn't fill field until page refreshes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Visual Studio 2012
MVC 5.1.1
ASP.Net Razor 3.1.1
bootstrap 3.1.1
jQuery 2.1.0
json.Net 6.0.1
Web Optimization 1.1.3
Webgrease 1.6.0
etc - most new extensions, etc

I have an MVC Web app with Telerik MVC KendoUI ComboBoxFor ComboBoxes in a razor partial view:

```
@model HTPortal.ViewModels.ClientInquiryViewModel
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressState, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2 
    col-md-2 col-lg-2" })
<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.AddressState)
        .Placeholder("Select Province...")
        .DataTextField("ProvinceName")
        .DataValueField("ProvinceName")
        .Suggest(true)
        .BindTo(Model.Provinces)
        )
    </div>

</div>
```

The data is loaded into the combobox - all ok.

In the parent razor page, after the @using (Html.BeginForm()) block, I have :

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function (data) {
                alert(data.region);
                //$("#AddressCity").val(data.city);
                $("#AddressState").val(data.region);
                //$("#AddressCountry").val(data.countryName);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

On the first page load, the alert does fire and I see my Province/State displayed in the alert.
However, my Combobox named AddressState only get filled after I refresh the page.

I've read various other posts on similar problems but no window load or init or anything works.

Infact, in IE and Chrome - all I get is the alert dialog - the fields are never filled.

Help....

How do I get this jQuery to fill the field the FIRST time the page is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't access the Kendo UI component correctly...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function (data) {
        $("#AddressCity").data("kendoComboBox").value(data.city);
        $("#AddressState").data("kendoComboBox").value(data.region);
        $("#AddressCountry").data("kendoComboBox").value(data.countryName);
    });
});
```

This works!